# Autocomplete comboBox that checks items in its list are entered

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Is there a way to check when an item is entered in a comboBox, is only one in which is actually in the list?  To explain further, if anything outside the list is selected it won't accept that input.  I've looked within stackoverflow but the only solution am seeing is that of changing my comboBox style to a dropdown list style.  The problem with this is that there are more than a hundred records to select from so the autocomplete on the comboBox is absolutely necessary to filter these out by the user input entered.

Updated(declared matched globally):

```
private void comboBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c = ((ComboBox)sender);
        string[] items = c.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
        matched = items.Any(i => i == c.Text.Trim().ToLower());

    }
```

and this is where it executes:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (matched==false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value in Carimed Items does not exist");
        }else
        {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox5.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select output file to be written to!");
        }
        else
        {

            //  int current = 0;
            if (comboBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All fields must be filled in before saving!");

            }
            else
            {


                    //  StringBuilder csvconten = new StringBuilder();
                    // csvconten.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}\r\n", comboBox2.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox2.Text, comboBox3.Text, textBox3.Text, comboBox1.Text);
                    // string csvpath = "cross_check.csv";
                    // File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvconten.ToString());

                    string connectionString3 = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacy_Output_File;Integrated Security=True";
                    string query3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.[" + comboBox5.Text + "] VALUES('" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + textBox7.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + textBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + comboBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "');";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString3))
                    {
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query3, connection);

                        command.Connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Connection.Close();

                    }


                    //   textBox1.Clear();
                    //     textBox3.Clear();
                    //   comboBox3.ResetText();

                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox3.Clear();
                    comboBox3.ResetText();
                    comboBox1.ResetText();
                }

                string connectionString2 = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
                string query2 = "UPDATE Liguanea_Lane2 SET Progress= '1' where code = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'; ";


                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                //this.liguanea_ProgressTableAdapter1.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet7.Liguanea_Progress);
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;
                //current = liguaneaLane2BindingSource.Position;
                //this.liguanea_Lane2TableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet3.Liguanea_Lane2);
                refreshDataGrid2();
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
                {

                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell =
                        dataGridView1
                        .Rows[Math.Min(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)]
                        .Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
                    // liguaneaLane2BindingSource.Position = Math.Min(current + 1, liguaneaLane2BindingSource.Count - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Won't a simple `AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend` do the trick ?

Comment: Tried that but it still allows free typing from the user.  Meaning they can type anything.

Comment: Even with `ComboboxStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` ?

Comment: Yup tried that also.  Still no luck.  @DeadlyJesus

Comment: Can't test it right now but are you sure that you used `DropDownList` and not `DropDown` since documentation says that "This means that the user cannot enter a new value."

Comment: As I stated in my initial post.  I did use drop down list but this is not workable as the are more than a hundred records.  The autocomplete is needed to filter the records. @DeadlyJesus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128435/discussion-between-deadlyjesus-and-jevon).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the `TextChanged` Event of the ComboBox to See if the enter text exsists in you list:

```
   private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox c = ((ComboBox)sender);
            string[] items = c.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
            bool matched = items.Any(i => i == c.Text.Trim().ToLower());
        }
```

You can declare the `matched` bool globally in the form that `TextChanged` event would assign its value then you can use it in other Methods like:

```
    void Button_Click(object sender, e EventArgs){
         if(matched)
    {
         //do something
    } else{
        // show an error message
    }

}
```

Comment: May I have an example please?

Comment: I added the example

Comment: Updated but it keeps popping up that the value doesn't exist even if it finds  a match